# Proving that maximal interval of existence exists and that solution is unque

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, partial-derivative

> For each $\lambda\in \mathbb{R}$, let $\varphi_{\lambda}$ : $J_{\lambda}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ denote the solution to the following initial value problem:
>   $$
> \frac{dy}{dx}=y^{2}+\lambda\sin^{2}x, y(0)=0,
> $$
>   where $J_{\lambda}$ is the maximal interval of existence.
>   
>   
> 1. Prove that for each $\lambda>0, J_{\lambda}$ exists and the above solution is unique; prove that $\varphi_{\lambda}$ is bounded.
>   
> 2. Let $\Phi(\lambda, x)=\varphi_{\lambda}(x)$. Calculate $\displaystyle \frac{\partial\Phi}{\partial\lambda}(0, x)$

For the first part:

"Let $f(x,y)=y^{2}+\lambda\sin^{2}x$.

Since $\displaystyle \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=2y$ is continuous, thus $f$ satisfies a local Lipschitz condition with respect to $y$, hence by the uniqueness theorem, the solution $\varphi_{\lambda}$ is unique.

Also by another theorem, the IVP has a unique maximal interval of existence, thus $J_{\lambda}$ exist. "


I am stuck at the next part as I not sure how to prove that $\varphi_{\lambda}$ is bounded.

Also, by using methods to solve a riccati equation:

let $P(x)=\lambda\sin^{2}x, Q(x)=0, R(x)=1.$

Then since $y_{0}=0$ is a particular solution of this IVP, I first define $z=\displaystyle \frac{1}{\varphi_{\lambda}}.$

Next, by theorem, 
$$
z'=-(0+2(0)(1))z-1=-1
$$
$$
z=-x+c_{1}
$$
So, $\varphi_{\lambda}$=$\displaystyle \frac{1}{c_{1}-x}.$

But since $y(0)=0,$ then I will get some undefined $c_{1}.$
Thus i am confused at this part.

Since I am unable to get $\varphi_{\lambda}(x)$, I couldn't attempt part 2.

Comment: Is Gronwall's inequality useful? http://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Gronwall_lemma